# The use of packages in java

Tags: java, package

I am splitting my project up in to packages and this is the first time I have used this, I normally just use the default package in eclipse but i read this is not the best idea.

What i was wondering is how granular do you make projects.

I have split distinct classes in to logical groups of functionality but this leaves some stragglers left over at the end in the top root of my main package. Is it ok to just leave those there or should they have their own package?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> leaves some stragglers left over at the end in the top root of my main package.  Is it ok to just leave those there or should they have their own package?

If those "stragglers" contain functionality used by the other classes, it might be better to put the in a "util" subpackage. Top packages usually contain classes that serve as a central access point to a framework or API, or (in the case of an application) that contain the main method and set up everything else.

Answer (score 1):

What stragglers are left? If it is some auxiliary utilities, you can create some package like `yourapp.utils` and put them there. Please provide a little more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about the fact that every project consists of modules. Think about toy blocks, that you put together to form your program.

You can imagine a package as a box where you can put another boxes or classes into.
Every package should have a clear responsibility, it could contains sub-packages or classes.
I think it is a nice project structure if you have every class in a specific package, where it is assumed to be.

So If you have structured your project in well considered packages and subpackages no class should be left alone without package. Try to find a good name for a package where it will fit into.

Maybe a "utils" package or "helper" package will a good name for something like that.

Hope I could help :)
Greetings